# Hydrophonic - Tomato plant - purple like leafs

Tags: tomatoes, hydroponic, nutrients

My hydrophonic tomato plant is showing some type of nutrition deficiency . don't know whats missing in my nutrition solution . Please help me[image: My hydrophonic tomato plant]

Comment: Hydrophonic? Like my headphones? You made me laugh. :-) Usually purple means not enough potassium, but that's a pretty young plant, and all sorts of awful things can happen at that stage, with weird symptoms. If you haven't already fertilized, I'd add a bit of a balanced fertilizer.